# Bluetooth Remote for Mac (for Plex)

Tags: bluetooth, remote-control, plex

So now that Macs no longer come with infrared I can't use the Apple Remote to control Plex, which is pretty disappointing.

Does anyone know of a good Bluetooth remotes that will work with Plex? I've seen the [Satechi Bluetooth Multimedia Remote](http://www.satechi.net/index.php/bluetooth/bluetooth-remote/satechi-bluetooth-remote-control), but it [looks like its not compatible](http://forums.plexapp.com/index.php/topic/67432-bluetooth-as-a-controller/).

Alternatively, I've seen this [Twisted Melon IR Receiver](http://twistedmelon.com/mira/hardware.html), however its pretty big and bulk so its far from an ideal solution.

Ive been using a combination of the iOS app and the Apple wireless keyboard, but none are idea. The iOS app doesn't remember the volume of the client, and freezes, and besides, I much prefer a physical keyboard.

Has anyone seen a small Bluetooth remote thats compatible with Plex (or, sends keyboard commands), or a small IR receiver compatible with Mac?

Comment: Haven't used Plex, but you could also consider local WiFi network remote, or using a bluetooth keyboard?

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for a wifi remote (I've never heard of them!

I have been using the Apple Wireless keyboard for the past 2 months, but it's certainly annoying trying to manage one of those on the couch or in bed.

Comment: Did a quick search on Plex, looks real cool! Wifi remotes are typically apps. There's one to handle iTunes or an Apple TV to do exactly what you'd need for Plex for those services. Also, I've used the L5 infrared adapter/free app to control TVs, Xboxs, Macs, etc. I recommend going to the app store and trying some of the free remotes. Search "Plex Remote"

Comment: Oh. Yeah. I have the Plex app which has a remote, but bugs aside, you can't beat having a physical remote.

Answer (score 2):

The [Satechi Bluetooth Smart Pointer](http://www.satechi.net/index.php/satechi-bluetooth-smart-pointer) is actually a pretty good choice. I have a number of teachers at this school who use it for their classes all the time. It works a lot like the Apple Remote that has been (essentially) discontinued for Macs. It has some additional features, like a laser pointer. To make it work with Plex, you can just use it in Accessibility Mode (this makes it behave more like a keyboard than a remote).

On a slightly unrelated note, it can also be used to control iOS devices, which I thought would be useless; but, it turns out to have some very convenient implementations around campus that I hadn't imagined.

Certainly worth $50, from my perspective.

Comment: Interesting... So Accessibility Mode will certainly set it to send keyboard commands?

Answer (score 0):

Plex is a bit limited, when it comes to remote support, in fact, [their forums](http://forums.plexapp.com) are filled with posts about remote-related problems.

I am pretty sure that no Bluetooth remote will work with Plex out of the box.

[Remote Buddy](http://www.iospirit.com/products/remotebuddy/hardware/?&ios_lang=en) is a great tool to get various remotes to work on a Mac (and Plex). It supports quite a decent amount of remotes, which are all listed on the site.

I would work down from there and also make my choices according to their supported hardware list.

Comment: Only Bluetooth remote on that list is the PS3 BD Remote :(

Comment: ...and the Wii remote. Agreed, not too many BT options, but I think the Wii remote would be a nice (few button) living room remote.

Answer (score -1):

Try [Satechi Bluetooth Smart Pointer.](http://www.satechi.net/index.php/satechi-bluetooth-smart-pointer)

Comment: Why is it good? (Welcome to the site - just use the edit button to add some details so that people can understand _why_ you are recommending this product).

Answer (score -1):

try your own iphone with the plex app...

Comment: The OP said that he tried the iOS app.